# Ignore some elements before a specific element and assign the rest to a new variable

Tags: python

I have a text file called 'price.txt' and it contains following data;

```
1=10.00
2=12.00
3=15.00
4=10.00
5=25.00
6=45.00
7=50.00
8=25.00
9=10.00
10=12.0
```

So when I go through a loop in a python program, I want to get the value assigned to the number '1' variable to a new variable. Is there any way to ignore elements before '=' mark and get the rest of the value to my new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just split the line that you read from file.

```
value = line.split('=')[1]
```

`line.split('=')[0]` will give you the value before `=` and `line.split('=')[1]` will give you the value after `=` because there is only two values before and after the `equal to` sign.

Example

```
line = '1=10.00'
print(line.split('=')[0]) # prints 1
print(line.split('=')[1]) # prints 10.00
```

---

**Update**

I am assuming you have all the texts in a list. Then you can iterate over the list and store the values in another variable.

```
lines = ['1=10.00', '2=12.00', '3=15.00', '4=10.00', '5=25.00', '6=45.00', 
                '7=50.00', '8=25.00', '9=10.00', '10=12.0']

variable = []
for line in lines:
    variable.append(float(line.split('=')[1]))

print(variable)
# prints -> [10.0, 12.0, 15.0, 10.0, 25.0, 45.0, 50.0, 25.0, 10.0, 12.0]
```

Comment: How can I use this in a for loop when user submit 1 or any of number and get the value assigned to that number to 'value' variable?